# How to add a click event on next button of "react-bootstrap-wizard" in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I am using react-bootstrap-wizard in which I need to call a function on next button and previous button on every specific tab form. How can I call a function then ?

```
<ReactWizard
  steps={steps}
  navSteps
  title=""
  subtitle=""
  headerTextCenter
  validate
  color="primary"
  finishButtonText="Submit"
  finishButtonClick={this.createCreator}
/>
```

Here all steps are rendered, now i need to call a function on NEXT and PREVIOUS buttons on specific step ?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/creativetimofficial/react-bootstrap-wizard/blob/master/index.js#L76) library doesn't allow you to handle `previous/next-ButtonClick` events.

You will need to file a feature request or create pull request yourself.

Comment: Which library/module I should use for my requirement ?